# How to send Hindi text to web server in android

Tags: android, web-services

I have created an application in which user can write issue in Hindi or English word. I am facing a problem i.e. when i write issue in Hindi word and send to web server then in admin portal it is not showing in the right format. But when I have got the response and show on list it is showing in the right format. Please suggest me how to fix this.

Comment: Please add code snippet else it will be difficult to tell where the problem is.

Comment: Are you using HTTP GET or HTTP POST?  People often try to send high-ASCII values via HTTP get without URL-Encodng them, and that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can send hindi text like this..

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(server_url);
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yourdata","value in hindi"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data",value));
```

encode the list in utf-8
like this and send.

```
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```